# Not able to complete installation of RTK query(of Redux Toolkit), I am getting an error

Tags: reactjs, node-modules, npm-install, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VN597.png)

In the above Image, I want to install RTK query and use it in my project. But it is not installing and giving me the above error.

I tried deleting node_modules folder and did npm install. After that still getting same error.

Also tried npm install multiple times and then tried to install the RTK query, still didn't worked.

I am not using VS code.(Few users were saying to close it and it will work). I am using sublime text, I close it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to `npm install @reduxjs/toolkit`. `@reduxjs/toolkit/query` is automatically installed as part of that, you don't need to install it separately.